# Are these endofunctor categories compactly accessible? (Given a suitable base...)

Tags: category-theory

[Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2113) we see a definition of compactly accessible categories.  [Endofunctor categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/endofunctor) have a monoidal product given as functor composition.  Let us take an object $O$ in the base category $C$.  Now consider the category of endofunctors that are identity everywhere, except on endomorphisms on $O$, which are mapped to endomorphisms on $O$.  In this way, we have endofunctor categories indexed by objects in $C$.  Considering the endofunctor category as defined above, is this endofunctor category compactly accessible?  Note, we have a freedom of choice of base category.  Can we choose a base category so that this endofunctor category is compactly accessible?

Comment: According to the linked definition, a compactly accessible category is _symmetric_ monoidal. The composition monoidal product on an endofunctor property is typically _not_ symmetric ($T \circ S \not \cong S \circ T$ typically), this isn't remedied by passing to the subcategory you're considering. So your question doesn't make sense as it stands. Also, this is a very strange category to consider -- for instance, if $C = Set$, then it consists only of the identity functor, regardless of which $O$ you choose. Do you have an interesting example of $C,O$ where this category is nontrivial?

Comment: I don't see how this could be the identity.  If the functor mapped all endomorphisms on $O$ to the identity morphism on $O$, that doesn't seem like an identity functor.  What am I missing here?  [I have a question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177663/symmetric-monoidal-dagger-endofunctor-categories) about how we can have lots of structure in our endofunctor category.  Would you be able to look there and maybe answer how we can at least have a symmetric monoidal product?

Comment: You want to have a functor $F: Set \to Set$ which is the identity on every homset except for $Set(2,2)$, say, but sends every arrow in $Set(2,2)$ to the identity? This is impossible. Consider the two maps $i_0,i_1:1 \to 2$ and the function $s: 2 \to 2$ which swaps 0 and 1. We have $i_0 = F(i_0) = F(s) \circ F(i_0) = F(s\circ i_0) = F(i_1) = i_1$ (using that $F$ is the identity on $Set(1,2)$, that $F(s)$ is the identity, and that $s \circ i_0 = i_1$), a contradiction. Regarding the other question, I would never expect an endofunctor category to be symmetric monoidal except in degenerate cases.

Comment: Thank you for your help here.  For the base category, I am thinking of the subcategory of CHU [as defined here in section 3.4](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0921v4.pdf).  Do we still end up in the situation where all functors of the above defined type are just the identity?

Comment: In that subcategory of CHU I linked to, we have a monoidal product.  So, I am interested in functors with the following property.  Given a compound system $A \otimes B$ the functor maps morphisms this way $F : f \otimes I \to I \otimes g$...I think.  I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: Let $e_1,e_2$ be endomorphisms of $O$. If there is $f: X \to 0$ such that $e_1 \circ f \neq e_2 \circ f$, then by the above argument, $F(e_1) \neq e_2$. That is, $F$ can only send $e_1$ to $e_2$ if $e_1,e_2$ are equalized by every map into $O$ from an object other than $O$. In most interesting categories, this is not the case, i.e. distinct endomorphisms can be distinguished by precomposition with _some_ other morphism. Maybe you can apply this meta-argument to the category you're interested to see that all such functors are the identity.

Comment: Thanks again for your help here.  I am going to revisit my definition for the functor, probably taking into account the tensor product...back to the drawing board